# Neutron star merger: large scale dynamics

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars

Yesterday was announced the first detection of a neutron star merger via gravitational and electromagnetic waves.

On the [announcement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFxLA3RGjnc&t=35m22s) one of the speakers is showing a simulation of the dynamics of the system before the merge.

No time scales are provided, and I am guessing is in the order of millions of years, but then the rotational speeds seem too slow, in relation to the orbital speeds of the system around the galaxy.

Does anyone have sources to the simulation or elements on the topic that might shed light into this?

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant LIGO papers?

Comment: E.g. https://dcc.ligo.org/LIGO-P1700264/public/main